# How to format JSON Object into slack message payload

Tags: slack

I have a json object that i want to use to send a message into a slack channel, how can i format this in the right way for slack to send a message?

i understand that slack uses the `{"text": "This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}` format, how can i get the below to fit the above format?

thank you

```
{
"Field_1": "4321",
"Field_11": "Store",
"Field_15": "Laptop",
"Field_6": "Dell",
"Field_8": "PRECISION",
"Field_132": "7560",
"Field_10": "abcde",
"Field_133": "43245",
"Field_13": "abcd",
"Field_161": "Canada",
"Field_2": "11/25/2021",
"Field_5": "Dell",
"Field_41": NaN
```

}

Comment: I recommend using Slack Block Kit Builder https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/ to find a format you want. After that, you can loop through the keys of your JSON object and create blocks in that format.